# Running a C program using execlp()?

Tags: c, linux, process, exec, fork

So I have a c program called "hello.c" that does nothing but "exit(2)" at the end. And I tried to run it in my child process, and then pass the return value into my parent process and print the appropriate messages. But somehow the program always exit at 0 and print the "exit at 0" message. Can someone tell me why?

```
pid_t pid;
int status;

pid = fork(); 

if (pid == -1){
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
} 
if (pid >0){
    /*abusive parents*/
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    if(WEXITSTATUS(status)==3){
        printf("exit at 3\n");
    }
    if(WEXITSTATUS(status)==2){
        printf("exit at 2\n");
    }
    if(!(WEXITSTATUS(status))){
        printf("exit at 0\n");
    }

}
else{
    /*stupid child*/
    execlp("hello.c",NULL);
}


return 0;}
```

Here is the hello.c:

```
int main(void){
   int teemo=0;

   exit(2);
}
```

Comment: You don't run a C program, you run the compiled executable... So `execlp("hello.c",NULL)` should be `execlp("hello.bin",NULL)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Still getting 0 though. Do I have to compiled that c program first?

Comment: If you are using an IDE, I suggest you stop using it for a while and switch to command-line tools. This should help you acquire some relevant intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not only) to better understand what is happeing in your code, add error checking.

In your specific case add it at least to the call to `execlp()`. To do so first have a look at [`exec*()`s documentation:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The exec() functions only return if an error has have occurred.  The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

And then enhance your code to cover this case:

```
    ...
  }
  else /* child */
  {
    if (-1 == execlp("hello.c"))
    {
      perror("execlp() failed");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You will observer an error message regarding the call to `execlp()`.

This dues to `hello.c` most probably not being an executable, but an ordinary text file, C-**source**.

---

Looking at the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) closer one reads:

> The list of
>          arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are
>          variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

From this we learn that a call to the `execl*()` members of the `exec*()` family of functions shall always end like this:

```
execlp(..., (char *) NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run a C source file, you need to compile (and link) it to generate an executable file, and run this file. Therefore, you should do something like

1. Compiling `hello.c` first (I suppose you are using `gcc`)

   ```
   gcc -o hello hello.c
   ```
2. Runing `hello` in your first program like this

   ```
   execlp("./hello", "hello", NULL);
   ```

Then you should get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add why its returning zero always in this case

This is because when execlp was failing and returning -1, parent process was using return value at the end of the main function i.e. 0 in this case. If you change this to 2 or 3 you will see program hitting that code with if check ==3 or ==2.